# Create variables with dynamic index in bash

Tags: bash, sh, posix, dynamic-variables

My code should work with #!/bin/sh
Is there a method how to declare a variables in loop with iteration number?
**CODE:**

```
n=0
somestring="asdf asdf"
while [ $n -le 10 ]
do
    "var$n"="$somestring"
done

# now it is possible to call variables var0, var1, var2,...
>> echo $var2
asdf asdf
```

Thank you for answer!

Comment: why not use an array instead?

Comment: Array is not supported in `#!/bin/sh` AFAIK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `export` :

```
while [ $n -le 10 ]
do
    export "var$n=$somestring"
    n=$((n+1))
done
```

Or `eval` :

```
while [ $n -le 10 ]
do
    eval "var$n=\"$somestring\""
    n=$((n+1))
done
```

Comment: Thank you!
You even answered question i didn't ask, and that why was eval not working, i missed `\\` there